# probability of getting 5 calls in 5 minutes

Tags: probability, random-variables

Phone calls arrive at the rate of 48 per hour at the reservation desk for Regional Airways.

1

a. Compute the probability of receiving three calls in a 5-minute interval of time.

b. Compute the probability of receiving exactly 10 calls in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use Poisson distribution with $\lambda_1 = 4, \lambda_2 = 12$.